# import module in Angular and get error from Scully

Tags: angular, import, build, scullyio

I try to use Scully in my Angular project.
In Angular, I have some Modules and I have to import in order to use.
But When I try to run with Scully

```
npm run scully --scanRoutes --showGuessError
```

it show this error

> belongs to more than one module:

```
PS C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb> npm run scully -- --scanRoutes --showGuessError

> si-web@0.0.0 scully C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb
> scully "--scanRoutes" "--showGuessError"

C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb
0.0.93
 ☺   new Angular build imported
 ☺   Started servers in background
Finding all routes in application.
traversing app for routes
Error: Module C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\src\app\home\home-routing.module.ts belongs to more than one module: C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\src\app\home\home.module.ts, C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\src\app\support\support.module.ts
    at Object.exports.getModuleEntryPoint (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\guess-parser\dist\guess-parser\index.js:395:15)
    at C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\guess-parser\dist\guess-parser\index.js:943:40
    at visitTopLevelRoutes (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\guess-parser\dist\guess-parser\index.js:910:13)
    at visitNodes (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18440:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18608:24)
    at NodeObject.forEachChild (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:134791:23)
    at visitTopLevelRoutes (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\guess-parser\dist\guess-parser\index.js:913:15)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18431:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:18525:21)
    at NodeObject.forEachChild (C:\Users\sportident\Documents\sportident_web\SiWeb\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:134791:23)

We encountered a problem while reading the routes from your applications source.
This might happen when there are lazy-loaded routes, that are not loaded,
Or when there are paths we can not resolve statically.
Check the routes in your app, rebuild and retry.
(You can inspect the error by passing the --showGuessError flag

When there are extraRoutes in your config, we will still try to render those.



FEHLER: Der Prozess "12072" wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Can someone please me how to fix this error?

**update**

this is the output from ng build

```
PS C:\Users\sportident\Documents\GitHub\Scully\SiWeb> ng build
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 281 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {center-center-module} center-center-module-es2015.js, center-center-module-es2015.js.map (center-center-module) 10.7 kB  [rendered]        
chunk {center-center-module} center-center-module-es5.js, center-center-module-es5.js.map (center-center-module) 12.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {blog-blog-module} blog-blog-module-es2015.js, blog-blog-module-es2015.js.map (blog-blog-module) 8.29 kB  [rendered]
chunk {blog-blog-module} blog-blog-module-es5.js, blog-blog-module-es5.js.map (blog-blog-module) 9.91 kB  [rendered]
chunk {other-other-module} other-other-module-es2015.js, other-other-module-es2015.js.map (other-other-module) 8.19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {other-other-module} other-other-module-es5.js, other-other-module-es5.js.map (other-other-module) 9.97 kB  [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 9.36 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 9.36 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 13.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {service-service-module} service-service-module-es2015.js, service-service-module-es2015.js.map (service-service-module) 13.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {service-service-module} service-service-module-es5.js, service-service-module-es5.js.map (service-service-module) 14.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {support-support-module} support-support-module-es2015.js, support-support-module-es2015.js.map (support-support-module) 39.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {support-support-module} support-support-module-es5.js, support-support-module-es5.js.map (support-support-module) 38.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 2.01 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 2.01 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 718 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {default~home-home-module~support-support-module} default~home-home-module~support-support-module-es2015.js, default~home-home-module~support-support-module-es2015.js.map (default~home-home-module~support-support-module) 948 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~home-home-module~support-support-module} default~home-home-module~support-support-module-es5.js, default~home-home-module~support-support-module-es5.js.map (default~home-home-module~support-support-module) 1.04 MB  [rendered]
```

**update with ng build --prod**

This is the output from ng build --prod

```
PS C:\Users\sportident\Documents\GitHub\Scully> ng build --prod
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {1} runtime-es2015.ec43354ddae7200524e5.js (runtime) 2.38 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} runtime-es5.ec43354ddae7200524e5.js (runtime) 2.38 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es2015.a06690f5899d30d926de.js (polyfills) 38.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es2015.44ea9a7d54a26a525593.js () 1.45 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es5.44ea9a7d54a26a525593.js () 1.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es2015.623601e1c9c733cffb63.js () 3.83 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es5.623601e1c9c733cffb63.js () 4.28 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es2015.779766a928981da4e7e7.js () 2.53 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es5.779766a928981da4e7e7.js () 3.08 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es2015.f825390b906e1c87c0b5.js () 5.55 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es5.f825390b906e1c87c0b5.js () 6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es2015.97f0f0a20b472ec18323.js () 20.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es5.97f0f0a20b472ec18323.js () 21 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} 0-es2015.60ea92d6ab2031a0dbec.js () 162 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} 0-es5.60ea92d6ab2031a0dbec.js () 174 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} polyfills-es5.5089fdacfadacafffdff.js (polyfills-es5) 131 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main-es2015.f2a2cccf2f7b508db936.js (main) 375 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main-es5.f2a2cccf2f7b508db936.js (main) 446 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es2015.a1a64491bbdb43c56434.js () 673 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es5.a1a64491bbdb43c56434.js () 823 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} styles.2c69555aa35ac891d5f5.css (styles) 151 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.debb52132dd62a12c627.js (scripts) 145 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-27T13:08:34.973Z - Hash: 5dbf1fa9b46942db407e - Time: 88346ms
```

Comment: What happens when you simply build your app using ng build —prod ?

Comment: Thanks for your asking @mike. I have updated it. pls take a look

Comment: Okay you didn’t do a a prod build it seems. However, my guess is that this is probably not a scully issue. The error indicates that your module setup is incorrect (ie a component is included in multiple modules). A prod build should give you that same error..

Comment: I have update with ng build --prod @MikeOne, but it looks like the same.

Comment: Right. I think you’ll have to look at the double import it reports..

Answer (score 2):

This is something that occasionally happens with the guess-parser we are using to find the routes in your application.

You can use the GuessParserOptions, and set the excludedFiles as illustrated below

```js
  export const config={
    handle404: 'baseOnly',
    thumbnails: true,
    /**
    * Add all the routes that give this issue in the excludedFiles array
    */
    guessParserOptions: {
      excludedFiles: ['\src\app\home\home-routing.module.ts'],
    },
    routes: {
      '/demo/:id': {
        type: 'extra',
        numberOfPages: 5,
      },
    },
  } as ScullyConfig;
```